# Design a generic IR remote interface

Tags: television, lirc

Im wondering if it is possible to design an interface that can auto-determine which lirc.conf to use.

Currently, Im using a raspberry pi to control my TV by using the specific lirc.conf for my TV remote.

Now if I put the device in a different area with a different TV, how could I determine which conf to use?

Let's say we know some basic information like the brand of the TV, is there any potential to create a combined lirc that would work for all models of that brand?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just have to handle a few remotes you can use all of the lirc.confs involved. lirc will try to decode the remote using each lirc.conf  sequentially, using the first match.

The details is heavily depending on your lirc version. For modern lirc, see http://lirc.org/html/configuration-guide.html#appendix-8.

Another option is to use the kernel decoding. If your remotes are supported by the kernel, you could just use the devinput driver and lircd.conf file, trusting the kernel decoding which determines the remotes in runtime.